# BaseX: best practice to hold xquery function

Tags: java, xquery, basex

Is the following possible for the BaseX database?

1. insert one or more XQuery functions into the database
2. call BaseX from Java, specifying which function to call, and receive a response

Or perhaps in a worse case:

1. Have a single file with all the XQuery functions I wish to define (this is certainly possible)
2. Somehow select a single function from that file and execute the query

At this moment I have a number of files, each of which contains a single xquery function. It is a bad solution; I would like to meet a more elegant one.

Comment: There is no such concept as stored procedures in BaseX. You simply put your functions as a library into your repository and simply call the function you want to call. See http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Repository for some more information.

Comment: thanks dirkk, it is the solution.